# android studio development and flutter development related

Tags: android

Guys I have doubt regarding android studio development and flutter development.

I recently started flutter development; So, I downloaded flutter and installed. But some time ago I needed to access my my old android project and I am not able to access my old android project(sending errors after errors). Before this it was working fine, tried to solve the error but unfortunately wasn't able to.

So, I want ask is 'does flutter have influence over android development?' like after installation of flutter in system android development not possible in same system or something else.

Please let me know if anyone knows anything about it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `regarding android studio development` you're not doing android studio development, you're using android studio FOR development, meaning that android studio is the IDE, which can support both android and flutter

Answer (score 0):

Installing Flutter won't affect the Android SDK whatsoever. You can run both Flutter and Native Android.

**Simply, got File --> Open --> and choose your project**

[image]

**Now select your old Android Project**

[image]

That is how you can access your old android project.

Thank you.

Comment: Yeah that's what I did but still I'm facing issue. But thanks for information.